# Makefile linking issues

Tags: c++, makefile

I wrote the [Makefile](http://pastebin.com/F3KLdREE) for an easier way to run the unit tests (the default target is test). The directories structure is as follows:

`lib` - google c++ test framework

`src` - source files

`test` - unit tests

In `src` I have the files `a.h`, `a.cc`, `b.cc` (which holds main) and I want to test class `A()` which is defined in `a.h`. All in all, because the order of linking is:

`g++ -Wall -c -o obj/src/a.o src/a.cc`

`g++ -Wall -c -o obj/src/b.o src/b.cc`

`g++ -o all obj/src/a.o`

I get the error:

`(.text+0x18): undefined reference to main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error`

even though I don't actually need a `main()` defined in `src` since I already have a `main()` defined in `test` which runs the unit tests.

Comment: Could you please post the actual output of "make clean all"?

Comment: @thiton: make clean all is pretty much broken and can be removed from that makefile ... it doesn't find the right paths

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand very well what you want to do, but if your main is in, say, test.o, you need to specify that in you linking line. For example:

```
g++ -o all obj/src/a.o test.o
```

Comment: I am just wondering: wouldn't this cause a circular dependency - test.cc needs a.h and at linking a.o needs test.o ?

Comment: @hyperboreean: I don't think there is cyclic dependency. a.o doesn't depend on test.o as a.o will have the class definition etc which test.o needs and not the other way around. It is test.o that will need a.o to be built into an executable.

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
g++ -o all obj/src/a.o
```

`g++` thinks you've asked it to build a executable, and accordingly is looking for the entry point. Presumably you meant to ask it for something else (a library, maybe?).

Comment: Yeah, it seems like creating a library would solve the problem - I am basically trying to learn something new and I am running the unit tests to see how the classes behaves instead of running the entry point (main()). So using a library seems a good approach to get rid of the currently not needed main() function.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it doesn't solve your current problem, it might be helpful to know that you are re-engineering `automake`. You shouldn't be writing Makefiles for C or C++ projects by hand nowadays.

Comment: automake is ugly in so many ways that I am better writing the Makefiles by hand rather than using it. I guess CMake and SCons are good options, though.

Comment: Well, an ugly thing for sure like all autotools, but at least it /works/ and gives you a Makefile for a project with all necessary targets and checks enabled. Have seen way too many projects with half-ass handwritten broken makefiles. Deploying projects where people tried to beat the autotools is in 99% of the cases a real pain in the ass. And CMake and SCons are no better - ever tried cross-compiling with them? Actually, ever tried cross-compiling with your Makefile? (Sorry for this whole rant, but I couldn't resist.)

Comment: In the end, how ugly anything can be, given the fact that I have 3 files (a.h, a.cc, a_test.cc) ? Hell, I can write a bash script to run it, I was going with a Makefile only to automate a bit my development cycle. Don't worry about the rant, I guess any critique can be seen as a constructive thing.